# Read column and ouptut files with the name of each row

Tags: bash, output, row

I work with genetics and I have this command line that retrieve me the DNA sequence of a gene:

```
search -db gene -query "glutaminase-asparaginase [Gene/Protein Name] AND (bacteria [orgn] OR fungi [orgn] OR archaea [orgn]) AND alive [prop]" | efetch -format docsum | xtract -pattern GenomicInfoType
-element ChrAccVer -element ChrStart -element ChrStop |xargs -n 3 sh -c 'efetch -db nuccore -id "$0" -seq_start "$1" -seq_stop "$2" -format fasta'
```

The output is like that (three sequences of three organism for the gene glutaminase-asparaginase):

```
>NC_030957.1:c4121890-4120582 Colletotrichum higginsianum
TGAGAGCTTCTTACTTGTCGACGCTGTTGTTGCCAGCTCTGGTAGCCCATGGTTTCGCCTCCCCAGTCGG
>NC_016603.1:c898826-897759 Acinetobacter pittii
TGTTGACTAAAACTGTTAAATCTTTAGGTTTAGCGATGGGCTTATTAG
>NC_002947.4:c2800289-2799201 Pseudomonas putida
TGAATGCCGCACTGAAAACCTTCGCCCCAAGCGCACTCGCCCTGCTGCTGATCCTGCCATCCAGCGCCTC
```

But I need to do this query with several gene names and generate output files with the sequences for each gene. I have in an Excel table like that:

```
glutaminase-asparaginase                 ColumnB ColumnC
Polyphosphate kinase                     ColumnB Columnc
Inositol-polyphosphate multikinase       ColumnB Columnc
```

I am trying to do this with this script:

```
for i in $( cat PATH_TO_TABLE | cut -f1 ); do 
 esearch -db gene -query "$i [Gene/Protein Name] AND (bacteria [org .... >>"$i".fasta
done
```

But the script only read the first word of the Column, for example in Polyphosphate kinase only reads "Polyphosphate" and the output file is Polyphosphate.fasta. when I need the query to be over "Polyphosphate kinase" and the output to be Polyphosphate_kinase.fasta

Can you help me with that? I will be grateful.

Comment: Hi, Is a bash script:

Comment: `#!/bin/sh
for i in $(  cat prueba.txt | cut -f1 ); do 
 esearch -db gene -query "$i [Gene/Protein Name] AND (bacteria [orgn] OR fungi [orgn] OR archaea [orgn]) AND alive [prop]" | efetch -format docsum | xtract -pattern GenomicInfoType -element ChrAccVer -element ChrStart -element ChrStop |xargs -n 3 sh -c 'efetch -db nuccore -id "$0" -seq_start "$1" -seq_stop "$2" -format fasta' >> "$i".fasta
done`

Answer (score 0):

Bash captures only the first word because it does not know if the second word is another column, or part of the first column.  This is caused by the space in the name.  To fix that, export your Excel file to CSV.  It will give you something like this:

```
glutaminase-asparaginase,ColumnB,ColumnC
Polyphosphate kinase,ColumnB,ColumnC
Inositol-polyphosphate multikinase,ColumnB,ColumnC
```

You can then cut on the `','` to split your columns.  Note that if you have data that contains `','` as well, this could be a problem.  Then you would export your Excel to CSV but with a `';'` separator (offered on my Excel).  And if you have both `','` and `';'`, the other option is to export to .txt with tab separators.  But then....  So you must chose the format that works the best for your data set ;-)

To replace the space by an `'_'`, you can use `echo "$Column1Value" | tr '[:space:]' '_'`.

Another option could be to replace all spaces by _ directly in the Excel spreadsheet, avoiding all this.